# LEFT JOIN in 'chain' through tables

Tags: mysql

I have a data structure in which fields refer to each table as follows:

`Table 1 
 INNER JOIN   Table 2
 LEFT JOIN    Table 3
 LEFT JOIN    Table 4
 ---------    LEFT JOIN Table 5`

I use Table 1 as the main table in the FROM statement from the query. Table 5 has a left join with table 4 **but** table 5 is also the one who will contribute the most with **the quantity** of data exported

`Table 1   Table 2       (...)    Table 5 (responsible for row number)
 name x  something x      ...            something x
 name x  something x      ...            something a
 name x  something x      ...            something b
 name x  something y      ...            something c
 name x  something z      ...            something s
 name y  something z      ...            something l
 name y  something z      ...            something v
 name y  something z      ...            something c`

So basically my query would be something like

`SELECT ... FROM table 1 LEFT JOIN table 4 (left join with table 5 with table 4???)`

How can this be done all in a single query?

Comment: That's not very clear. Can you be more specific? (Maybe show the columns you want to join on?)

Comment: I don't really get your table structure, and what you want to achieve. In general you'll need to reference the tables (columns) to be able to join them.

Comment: please provide additional table information

Comment: I have a feeling you're seeing problems where there aren't any. It looks like you are aware of the difference between inner and outer joins. Now all you need to do is join your tables using the appropriate `ON` conditions, there is no need to put `JOIN` clauses in parentheses. Try it out and if it doesn't work, post your complete query.